# Can't send keys in "Chrome://" like pages - Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

hope that you are doing well, I'm trying to change my profile name in chrome using Selenium, but it seems that I can't access the input element, each time I'm facing this Exception:  `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method": "CSS selector", "selector":"#input"}`. I tried every selector from XPath, javascript path, and CSS selector to partial link text. What it seemed to work a little was sending `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);` but that depends on the actual position.
Does anyone know a solution or an alternative to this problem?
This is my Java code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.CharSet;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class TestTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("chrome://settings/manageProfile");
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
//      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
//      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#inner-input-container")).sendKeys("Ayoub");

//      driver.close();
    }
        
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Shadow-root element here. In selenium to handle shadow root elements, you need to do some extra work.
Expand the shadow-root elements first then access the element.

```
public WebElement expandRootElement(WebElement element) {
    WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
    return ele;
}
```

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver

Comment: Thank you so much thanks to you and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQcRaIoc2AM everything is clear